Batch items in Tensorflow Dataset that contain varying first dimension, but constant second dimension
I have a Tensorflow dataset that contains tensors of rank 2. Each tensor was read from a file and has varying first dimension and constant second dimension. For example, the shapes of each item can be the following:
(123, 3)
(100, 3)
(134, 3)
...

To simulate similar behavior you can use the following:
lengths = tf.random.uniform(shape=(10,), minval=5, maxval=10, dtype=tf.int32)
# this would be a dataset of filenames in my code
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(lengths)

def fake_read_file(tensor):
    # this function would read and preprocess data from file in my code
    # however, for demonstration purposes it just returns a dummy data with varying length in the first dimension
    dummy_data = tf.convert_to_tensor([[0.2, 0.2, 0.2]])
    return tf.repeat(dummy_data, tensor, axis=0)

# I use tf.py_function decorator because file read can be done only in eager mode
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(fake_read_file, inp=[x], Tout=tf.float32))

I need to batch this dataset using RaggedTensors (I don't want to pad the input). The dimensions of each batch should be (batch_size, None, 3).
Right now I came up with the following solution:
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(x))
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=2, drop_remainder=True)

However, when I iterate over the dataset I get the batches of shape (batch_size, None, None), i.e. the last dimension gets ragged too.

The workaround I found to solve this problem is to add a dummy dimension before converting the tensors to ragged tensors and then remove this dimension after batching:
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(x, 0))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(x))
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=2, drop_remainder=True)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: tf.squeeze(x, axis=1))

I don't know the reason why Tensorflow behaves this way, but now it produces correct batches. Additionally, when you iterate over elements in a batch, you will get regular tensors (of different shapes) instead of ragged tensors as it used to be before.
